# Android Debugging - Simulate unplugged phone

Tags: android, debugging, service, alarm, commonsware-cwac

I have a program that works great when its plugged in.  But, when its unplugged I am having a problem somewhere in the program.  I don't know where in the program the problem is coming from because its unplugged from eclipse.

Is there a way to simulate or make the phone believe its not plugged in, or some other method for debugging in this situation so that i may track down why the program is not functioning as desired in this circumstance.

To give a little insight in the program.  I have a START_STICKY services that initiates an Alarm and doWakefulWork do accomplish a task every 15 minutes. I find that the tasks sometimes stop working.  I am trying to figure out where the loose link is...

Hope there are some good answers out there..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this option >> go to run >> remove all breakpoints 
Hope this will work because it happened to me once

Answer (score 0):

You can trace method calls and dump them into a trace file. Follow [this guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) to do that.

Also, you can start a task every 15 minutes with the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). The problem with your app might (or might not be) that the device is going to sleep. AlarmManager will probably do the work, if you're not using it already.

Other thing you might do to keep the service running is acquiring a [wake lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html). This solution, however, might drain your battery, so sticking with AlarmManager should be the way to go! Good luck!

Comment: Yes, i am using the AlarmManager.  On the OnReceiver from the triggered AlarmManager, i am using the WakefulIntentService to intiate doWakefulWork. -  Under these circumstances, short of turning off the device, the program should continue to work.  But, alas, that does not seem to be the case when the unit is in an unplugged state for a XX amount of time.  I will look at that guide that you posted a link too.. I appreciate that..

Comment: Sorry! I didn't realize that you were using the cwac-wakeful library. I have no experience with it, and don't know what might have gone wrong. I can only assume that the WakeLock is not held long enough for the operations to finish... Maybe try acquiring a wake lock on your own? Good luck anyways!

Comment: Also you can add a cwac-wakeful tag to your question. I'd do that, but I don't want to remove any of the current tags :)